# How do you show hidden rows in Excel chart, but NOT hidden columns?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to enable an Excel chart to plot data in hidden rows, but NOT in hidden columns? I already know how to use the "Select data" option, when right clicking a chart, to go to the "Hidden and empty cells" option, which offers the choice to "Show data in hidden rows and columns". I can't find a way, however, to show data in hidden rows without also showing data in hidden columns and was hoping someone might be able to suggest a VBA solution.

Many thanks,

Geoff

Comment: There may be a better way out there, but you could create the chart from scratch and loop through the columns in your data range, choosing to add only the visible columns. Alternatively, you could leave `Show data in hidden rows and columns` checked and use VBA to loop through the series values to see if the column is hidden, and if so, to remove that series from the chart.

Comment: Thanks Scott. That definitely sounds worth a shot. I'm not too sure about how I go about creating such code, though. Is there some generic code you can offer for the second option you suggested, assuming, say, that columns D:AE are all populated and that under different scenarios, different columns would be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I just drummed this up for you. As a caveat, working with charts can be very tricky. This code will only work with certain types of charts, and you may have to make some adjustments to work with your particular data set.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveHiddenColumns()

Dim myChart As ChartObject
Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1") 'place in here whichever chart you need to reference, asssumes the chart is on the activesheet

myChart.Activate 'first activate the chart

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count 'loop through each series

    Dim strText As String, strCol As String, strSht As String, intCol As Integer

    strText = Split(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Formula, ",")(2) 'extract sheet name and column of series
    strSht = Split(strText, "!")(0) 'get sheet name of series
    strCol = Split(strText, "!")(1) 'get column range of series

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets(strSht)

    If wks.Range(strCol).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then 'if the column is hidden
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Delete 'remove the series
    End If

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a huge help and I really appreciate your efforts!

Comment: It was a great question. I enjoyed solving it :)